# NodeJS with socket.io and postgres LISTEN

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, pg

I'm trying to get my frontend to watch for events whenever a certain table on my postgres db is altered.

The Postgres events fire perfectly and I'm able to relay them to through the Socker.io connection, but I'm having reliability issues. I'm getting `(node:26) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Client was closed and is not queryable`  errors on my server and often events are not emitted and caught by Socket. I'm assume it has to do with the way I connect to Socket / db clients.

pg config:

```
const {Pool} = require('pg');
const production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const connectionString = `postgresql://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.DB_HOST}:${process.env.DB_PORT}/${process.env.DB_DATABASE}`

const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: process.env.CONNECTION_STRING ? process.env.CONNECTION_STRING : connectionString,
  ssl: production,
  connectionTimeoutMillis : 5000,
  idleTimeoutMillis : 30000
});
```

index.js

```
io.of("/marketDetails").on('connect', (socket) => {
  pool.connect((err, client, release) => {
    if (err) { 
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    
    client.query('LISTEN update_table');
    
    client.on('notification', async(data) => {
      console.log("notified of table change")
      handleDBEvent(socket, data);
    })

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      client.query('UNLISTEN update_table');

    })
    
    release();
  })
});
```

I get notified on certain table changes but very inconsistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are immediately `release`ing the database client that you acquired, before any notifications can happen, and you're getting the error message every time the socket disconnects and you try to run the `UNLISTEN` command on the released client whose connection was closed after 30s.

Instead, use

```
socket.on("disconnect", async () => {
  try {
    await client.query('UNLISTEN update_table');
  } finally {
    release();
  }
});
```

Btw I would recommend not to acquire a new database connection for each socket.io client, the database is far too valuable for that. Instead, create a single client for your app (you might not even need a pool), have it listen to the `update_table` events (maybe only when sockets are connected), and then [broadcast](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-emit-eventName-%E2%80%A6args) each event to all currently-connected sockets.